# Android - Pushbots NullpointerException if app is not running

Tags: android, notifications, nullpointerexception, push

I just implemented the Pushbots library in my project. If my application is running the push notifications works great. But if the application is not running it always crashes. 
I used the logcat and it says following:

```
 09-26 02:40:28.143: E/AndroidRuntime(18464): FATAL EXCEPTION:       
 IntentService[GCMIntentService--1]
 09-26 02:40:28.143: E/AndroidRuntime(18464): java.lang.NullPointerException
 09-26 02:40:28.143: E/AndroidRuntime(18464):   at   
 com.pushbots.push.Pushbots.regID(Pushbots.java:409)
 09-26 02:40:28.143: E/AndroidRuntime(18464):   at 
 com.pushbots.push.Pushbots.sendStatsToServer(Pushbots.java:282)
 09-26 02:40:28.143: E/AndroidRuntime(18464):   at 
 com.pushbots.push.GCMIntentService.onMessage(GCMIntentService.java:112)
 09-26 02:40:28.143: E/AndroidRuntime(18464):   at     com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService.onHandleIntent(GCMBaseIntentService.java:191)
 09-26 02:40:28.143: E/AndroidRuntime(18464):   at   
 android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
 09-26 02:40:28.143: E/AndroidRuntime(18464):   at  
 android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 09-26 02:40:28.143: E/AndroidRuntime(18464):   at    
 android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
 09-26 02:40:28.143: E/AndroidRuntime(18464):   at   
 android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
 09-26 02:40:28.143: E/PowerManagerService(2116): WakeLock : binderDied()
```

How can I fix this NullPointerException?

Answer (score 1):

Actually this is a bug.

You can fix this By creating separate Application class.

```
package com.pusbots.androidpushbot;
import android.app.Application;
import com.pushbots.push.Pushbots;
public class SampleApplication extends Application {
private static final String SENDER_ID ="YOUR_SENDER_ID";
private static final String PUSHBOTS_APPLICATION_ID ="PUSHBOT_APP_ID";
    @Override 
   public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();
        Pushbots.init(this, SENDER_ID, PUSHBOTS_APPLICATION_ID);
    }
}
```

see this video tutorial : [Send GCM Android Push Notifications](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=faop6vBBe3E)

Also check this : [pushbots-app-crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19344477/pushbots-app-crash)
[app not running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19452144/pushbot-recieving-push-notifications-crashes-app-when-its-not-running)