# PushBots App Crash

Tags: android, push-notification

I am making an Android App which uses Push Notification services using PushBots.

What i want to do is, when i receive an Push Notification, I want to save the Message in an TextView, so that i can have an History of all the Messages Received..

I did everything that is written on the PushBots website to receive The Push Notification, and I am even Successfully only and only when the App is open..

If i Receive an notification when the App is not running on the Phone, then the App Crashes.

So Please can you help me to solve this App crashing Problem?? And even help me to show the Received msg in an TextView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the video tutorial on youtube (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=faop6vBBe3E)

I'll quote here too:

> Please make sure you've copied PushBots.jar file into libraries folder of your android project.
>   And also make sure you extended Application Class, and initialized PushBots in its onCreate method, check out steps 6,7 in this link for more details https://pushbots.com/developer/tutorial#/android/existing/step/4

here's a sample code:

```
import com.pushbots.push.Pushbots;
import android.app.Application;

public class MyApplication extends Application {
  @Override
  public void onCreate() { 
    super.onCreate();
    Pushbots.init(this, "", "");
  }
}
```

Comment: I had written the init method in onCreate method which was inside the class extended by Activity.. When i wrote the init method inside the Allication class it stopped crashing..